# Text expands outside the div it's inside?

Tags: css, html

I've got this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    width: 60em;
    margin: 0, auto;
    background-color: #CCC;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div id="content">kdsjlglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgkhlglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgkkjdghkdsfjgksdjfhg</div>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Why does the text not stay inside the div, but go in a single line until it ends? I want it to have line breaks relative to the div it's inside. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because word wrapping occurs *between* words.

At least by default. The [word-break property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#word-break) can change that in some browsers, but you should avoid having nonsensical 'words' in the content.

Answer (score 5):

Use the CSS attribute "word-wrap: "

```
#content {
width: 60em;
margin: 0, auto;
background-color: #CCC;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

}

This used to be IE only, but I have seen it working in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

**[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRVGk/)**

```
#content { word-wrap: break-word; }
```