# Overflow in div tag

Tags: css

I have a div tag with fixed width. Now i want that if there is a condition of overflow then text should go to next line automatically. I used overflow:auto but its giving a horizontal scroll bar. There should not be any scroll bar, text should go to next line.

Any idea how to do it with css???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text expands outside the div it's inside?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489385/text-expands-outside-the-div-its-inside)

Comment: what about white-space css attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a scrollbar to appear for when text fills more than the height of a div, you can try:

> overflow-y:auto

You might also need word-wrap or white-space css attributes?

Answer (score 0):

to add to the link David's pasted, if you want the vertical scrollbar to show up, then the `height` property of the div should be fixed.